# How to open Firefox bookmarks html backup in Epiphany?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, gnome3

I have an .html file, which was created with "Export Bookmarks to HTML…" tool in Firefox. When I try to open it with Gnome Web Browser (Epiphany), the browser downloads the file instead of displaying. How to open the file in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox bookmarks file declares itself in a way that Epiphany does not recognise it as an HTML file, so it just downloads it. Open the file with a text editor, such as Gedit, replace the first line, which is something like `<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>`, with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and save. Open the file as usual.